# phpize's config.m4 with more than one source file in PHP_NEW_EXTENSION produces a Makefile that does nothing

Tags: php, c, makefile, autoconf, php-extension

I am trying to write a C extension to PHP.  This is my config.m4.  Straight out of helloworld, almost

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(my_ext, whether to enable my_ext support,
[ --enable-my-ext   Enable My Ext support])

if test "$PHP_MY_EXT" = "yes"; then
  AC_DEFINE(HAVE_MY_EXT, 1, [Whether you have my ext])
  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(my_ext, my_ext.c,  $ext_shared)
fi
```

When I run phpize and ./configure, it generates a Makefile that works.  **Looking good so far.**

Now, if I add an **additional source file to PHP_NEW_EXTENSION**, things break down.  As per [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-18.9/php/README.UNIX-BUILD-SYSTEM) and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.buildsys.configunix.php), the call should look like:

```
PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(foo, foo.c bar.c baz.cpp, $ext_shared)
```

The full syntax:

```
PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(extname, sources [, shared [,sapi_class[, extra-cflags]]])
```

Ok, so I add my extra source file (logging.c) to that list:

```
PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(my_ext, my_ext.c, logging.c  $ext_shared)
```

and phpize/configure **produce a Makefile that runs successfully, but does not actually build anything.**  (yes, I've done make distclean, phpize --clean, etc.)

I diffed the successful Makefile vs. the broken one, and here are the differences:

```
$ diff Makefile Makefile.broken 
14d13
< shared_objects_my_ext = my_ext.lo
16c15
< PHP_MODULES = $(phplibdir)/my_ext.la
---
> PHP_MODULES =
170,175d168
< $(phplibdir)/my_ext.la: ./my_ext.la
<   $(LIBTOOL) --mode=install cp ./my_ext.la $(phplibdir)
< 
< ./my_ext.la: $(shared_objects_my_ext) $(MY_EXT_SHARED_DEPENDENCIES)
<   $(LIBTOOL) --mode=link $(CC) $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS_CLEAN) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath $(phplibdir) $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS) $(shared_objects_my_ext) $(MY_EXT_SHARED_LIBADD)
<
```

Anyone know what is going on here?

BTW, if I leave out the extra source file, I get compiler warnings about functions in that file having "internal linkage but is not defined".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try moving the 2nd comma

`PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(my_ext, my_ext.c, logging.c  $ext_shared)`

To

`PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(my_ext, my_ext.c logging.c, $ext_shared)`

If I understand the documentation correctly, the 2nd argument should be a space separated list of your sources.